# I'm getting deprecated dependencies when I'm installing Nuxt template in powershell

Tags: npm, dependencies, nuxt.js

I have downloaded a VueJs template with good reviews, upadeted recently. But when I'm installing the package I'm getting errors like deprecated dependencies or requires peer of *package*. I've contacted the technical support and they told me that the problem come from my env.

```
npm WARN eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.2 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-awesome-swiper@4.1.1 requires a peer of swiper@^5.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

83 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 84 vulnerabilities (35 low, 25 moderate, 24 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I've tried to update and re-install my dependencies for a couple of time, I even change 3 times of node version.
Does someone have already get this kind of issues ?